# how to automate Y in a script during an rpm install

Tags: scripting, software-installation, rpm

I need to create an automated install of an snmpv3 package. I have been able to install it manually, but how do i add it in a script, and automate the "Y" response when prompted in a script during the installation?

Comment: Could you post the the output and the actual command you are using?

Comment: when i run " yum install net-snmp-utils net-snmp-devel" manually, the following comes up "Is this ok [y/N], I enter a "y" and the install proceed, my question is, how do i automate the "y" response in is a script?

Comment: Could you please edit your question, adding this yum command?

Comment: resolved, from what i gather, i just have to append the -y on the yum install command...this will eliminate unnecessary step..thanks to all of you for taking the time and guiding me...

Answer (score 0):

`yum -y install ...`

More generic, if you are to lazy to read yum's man page, you could pipe `yes` into your yum command:

`yes | yum install ...`